# Linq query only returning first item of array

Tags: c#, linq

Let the string projects equal "p1,p2,p3" and in the database the identifier for each exists as follows p1 = 1 ,p2 = 2, p3 = 3.  Only the first project in the list is being returned in my query, any thoughts on why?

```
private List<int> getProjects(string projects)
    {

        String[] projectArray = projects.Split(',');

        QMOIIEntities db = new QMOIIEntities();

        var projectList = db.wbs_projects
          .Where(x => projectArray.Contains(x.prjName))
          .Select(x => x.prjID).ToList();

        return projectList;
    }
```

****UPDATE
This issue was whitespace in the string I changed

```
String[] projectArray = projects.Split(',');
```

to

```
 String[] projectArray = projects.Trim().Split(',');
```

Comment: This looks like a data related issue. Can you give sample data of what db.wbs_projects looks like?

Comment: Your indentation is very confusing - it would have been better to leave the `Contains` call on the same line as the `Where` call, given that it's part of it - not a peer of it, which is what your formatting makes it look like.

Comment: And did you triple-check that `projectArray` contains what you think it does? And the same for the Db. `P2` or `p2 ` instead of `p2` would do it.

Comment: On a lighter note, if you declare your variable as List<string>, then please do not call it as "projectArray".

Comment: I verified everything in the database, and ran it through a debugger. I am pretty sure it isn't a data issue.

Comment: @Pawan changed it to a list from an array to see if that was the issue without refactoring. Nice catch though

Comment: @crocaduck81: Have you checked what SQL is being executed?

Comment: @Jon can't seem to figure out how to do that in the VS debugger any references?

Comment: @crocaduck81: Assuming this is LINQ to SQL, use the Log property.

Answer (score 4):

The following code uses the same logic, the one you have mentioned in your question. I have created dummy data. The code is behaving as expected i.e. the output is the prjID corresponding to each prjName.

```
void Main()
{
    string projects = "p1,p2,p3";
    List<string> projectArray = projects.Split(',').ToList();

    TestEntities db = new TestEntities();
    db.wbs_projects = new List<TestEntities>();
    db.wbs_projects.Add(new TestEntities(){prjName = "p1",prjID="Test1"});
    db.wbs_projects.Add(new TestEntities(){prjName = "p2",prjID="Test2"});
    db.wbs_projects.Add(new TestEntities(){prjName = "p3",prjID="Test3"});

    var projectList = db.wbs_projects
      .Where(x => projectArray.Contains(x.prjName))
      .Select(x => x.prjID).ToList();

    foreach(var item in projectList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);//Test1,Test2,Test3
    }

}

public class TestEntities
{   
    public List<TestEntities> wbs_projects{get;set;}

    public string prjName{get;set;}
    public string prjID{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for testing the code, made me check the string and I found whitespace in it, updated above...

Comment: it is the way the string was being returned, was like "p1, p2, p3" so I had to trim it.